# Converting shapefiles using shp2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I know where `shp2pgsql` is in the postgresql directory but I'm not sure what commands to use after that. I've read the manual thoroughly, and I am aware of all the arguments and options for the `shp2pgsql` command. I get the error:

```
-bash: shp2pgsql: command not found
```

Is it a permissions problem perhaps?

Comment: sounds like a `PATH` issue. Does `which shp2pgsql` show where it is?

Comment: Yes you're right I exported the initial directory to $PATH and it worked a treat thanks very much for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to export the path of the program and put it into $PATH variable.
Another option is to move the command into directories already contained in PATH such as /usr/bin.

Example
export PATH=/Library/Postgresql/9.0/bin/:$PATH
                             or

1. echo $PATH to find directories already there
2. Go to directory with the program in it
3. mv shp2pgsql /usr/bin for example

Answer (score 12):

The right command is «shp2pgsql», you have got a typo.

Usage example :

```
# shp2pgsql -c -D -s 4269 -I shaperoads.shp myschema.roadstable > roads.sql
# psql -d roadsdb -f roads.sql
```

- -c creates the table
- -I creates an index on geometry
- -D uses dump format
- -s specify projection srid

You first generate a sql file, which you then load into your database.

Comment: sorry about the typo im still getting-bash: roads.sql: Permission denied

Comment: For those coming to this thread for usage with shp2pgsql, you can also pipe the output of `shp2pgsql` directly to `psql` rather than save the intermediate SQL file.  The above example would look like: `shp2pgsql -c -D -s 4269 -I shaperoads.shp myschema.roadstable | psql -d roadsdb` For more information, check out the [Boston GIS shp2pgsql cheat sheet](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg).